# How to write the equation number manually?

Tags: equations, numbering

Does anyone know how to number an equation manually? I know using `\begin{equation}` automatically numbers the equation but I want to number it manually.

Like this:

```
ax=b                      2.1

ax=b                      2.2
```

etc.

Comment: Any specific reason, why you want to number them manually?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [amsmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package and the `\tag` command. If you don't want the parenthesis, use `\tag*`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        ax= b \tag{2.1}
    \end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And still be able to use `\label` and `\eqref`!